# Installanywhere for linux distributions

Tags: linux, centos-7

I need to know whether the Installanywhere software is available free for linux distributions. I was able to find windows installable versions from internet, but couldn't find for linux. Can someone help on this? Thank you.

Comment: does it work with WINE? it is a windows emulator for linux.

Comment: have you asked [their support](https://www.revenera.com/about-us/contact-us.html) about it also?

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the download page you found? from a simple google it seems as though InstallAnywhere is a java-based tool, which means it should run on linux, but whether it was designed to be able to install things on linux/unix-like filesystems is a different story